First time wine maker
Good morning , I’m a first time wine maker and have a question about the wine I’m making , I made 4 gallons of scuppernong wine. I used 2 1/2 gallons of grapes, 2 gallons of water, 4 pounds of sugar and one pack of yeast. I let it set for two weeks then I removed the grapes and strained the wine, then added another 4 pounds of sugar and another pack of yeast. My question is, I’m into my 3rd week of fermentation. Can I still add potassium sorbate to my batch and should I add something else? I hope I didn’t mess up because I bought bottles, corks and labels for my wine. Appreciate any advice

I brew cider, but the basics of fermentation really come down to:
yeast + sugar = alcohol + Co2. If you add potassium sorbate, the current generation of yeast can no longer reproduce. If they can't reproduce, they can't ferment.
With cider, after fermentation finishes, I rack the cider into a keg with an airloc on it and let any yeast finish up whatever may be left in there. Then I'll add Potassium sorbate to the keg a couple days before back sweetening. Then, the day before, I'll add some Potassium Metabisulfite.
The Pots. S. stops the current generation of yeast from reproducing, and the Pots. M. is there to further stabilize and help prevent spoilage and oxidation[1].
I would think as long as your wine it's still fermenting (almost a couple weeks from your post, now) you're good. Just make sure fermentation has finished before adding the stabilizers. If you're not sure it's finished, just measure the gravity with a refractometer a couple days apart. If it's not changed, it's done.
[1] https://www.smartwinemaking.com/post/potassium-sorbate-vs-potassium-metabisulfite
